# Displaying search result on same page without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

While browsing a website i found an interesting feature that i like to have in my application.It is like displaying search result on same page without refreshing the page. When someone fills the last field of the form it shows the search result on the same page without refreshing the page.The form has no submit button or any link to submit the form data when someone fills the last field it search result and display the result. I want to implement this feature in my application i built in PHP. I know this can be done by Javascript & Ajax but i don't have enough knowledge of these languages. I just learned HTML,CSS,PHp & MySql. Let me show u my code

HTML:

```
<form action="do_search.php" method="post"/>
Enter Number:<input type="text" name="roll" id="roll">
<input type="submit" value="search record"/>
```

do_search.php:

```
    <?php
    include 'includes/dbConnect.php';   
?>
<?php
    $roll = $_POST['roll'];
    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM students WHERE Roll_No = '$roll'" ) or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    ?>
<table width="100%"  bgcolor="#F7F7F7" border="0">
<?php
if ($num_rows!=0)
{
?>
<tr style="text-align:left;">
    <td width="7%" align="center" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" bgcolor="#996600" class="heading"><strong>#</strong></td>
    <td width="13%" align="left" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" bgcolor="#996600" class="heading"><strong>Roll No</strong></td>
    <td width="29%" align="left" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" bgcolor="#996600"class="heading"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td width="23%" align="left" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" bgcolor="#996600" class="heading"><strong>Father Name</strong></td>
    <td width="16%" align="center" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" bgcolor="#996600" class="heading"><strong>Class</strong></td>
    <td width="12%" align="center" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" bgcolor="#996600" class="heading"><strong>Section</strong></td>

</tr>
    <?php
//$counter = 1;
    while ($get_info = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        print '<tr class="text-data">';
        print '<td align="center" valign="top">' . $get_info[0] . '</td>';
        print '<td align="left" valign="top">
        <a href="edit_Student.php?roll_no=' . $get_info[1] . '" style="color:#000"><b>' . $get_info[1] . '</b></td>';
        print '<td align="left" valign="top">'. $get_info[2] . '</td>';
        print '<td align="left" valign="top">' . $get_info[3] . '</td>';
        print '<td align="center" valign="top">' . $get_info[4] . '</td>';
        print '<td align="center" valign="top">' . $get_info[5] . '</td>';
        print '</tr>';
        //$counter++; 
    }
}
else
{
?>
<tr style="text-align:left;">
    <td align="center" colspan="7">
        No Student Found !
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

This is working fine for me and display the record on do_search.php page. I want my form has no submit button option & when someone enter the form field Enter Roll Number it should display the record on same page and display all the record from database. Can anyone please help me for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Standard warning - you are leaving yourself open to injection attacks by not sanitizing your $_POST input, and mysql_ functions have been deprecated. Aside that, jQuery can be set to listen on elements. Google search "jquery on" and read up. Listen on your last field blur, then google "jquery ajax" and read up on the .ajax method. They both come with enough examples to pretty much write your code for you.

Comment: @Majid: jQuery is easy to pick up, however I recommend learning Javascript. So, if you just want to get things done, jQuery is easy to pick up and you can easily implement what you want with it. As you learn and are stuck with something, you can always post here.

Comment: @Aravind i will study all the examples in detail. can you show me a sample code for my search for what i am trying to achieve. Thanks :)

Comment: @MajidAli: These will help you: https://api.jquery.com/change/, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, and https://api.jquery.com/html/. With these three, you can complete the functionality that you want to do.

Comment: See https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ , https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with jQuery ajax.

```
<form action="do_search.php" method="post"/>
 Enter Number:<input type="text" name="roll" id="roll">
</form>    
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#roll").change(function() {
      $.post("do_search.php", { roll:$("#roll").val() })
     .done(function( data ) {
         $("#result").html(data);
     });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jqyery keydown() Method

```
$("input").keydown(function(){
    //Do display logic
    // Use Ajax and get the data for the value enter and update your html content
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keydown.asp